# Android play video in TextureView from raw or assets

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I'm having an annoying problem with playing a video in TextureView from raw or assets folder... or even from the external storage. The code in the fragment looks something like this

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener {
    private ParallaxAdapter mAdapter;

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer2;
    private TextureView tv;
    private TextureView tv2;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private TextureView mTexture;
    String path;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstance);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_fragment, container, false);

        path = getArguments().getString("path");
        Log.d("Fragment","" + path);

        String tag = getArguments().getString("Tag");
        imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        if (tag == "image") {
            imageview.setImageResource(getArguments().getInt("image"));

        } else if (tag == "video") {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inDither = false;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmapThumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmapThumb);

            tv = (TextureView) v.findViewById(R.id.textureView);
            tv.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);
        }

        return v;
    }

    public void setAdapter(ParallaxAdapter Adapter) {
        mAdapter = Adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
        Surface s = new Surface(surface);
        try {
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setDataSource(path);
            mp.setSurface(s);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setVolume(0, 0);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the MediaPlayer cannot find the file from raw:

```
defpath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video;
```

or from assets:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(FILE_NAME);
mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
```

and i've tried to copy the assets to the sdcard with some codes from this discussion: [android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard)

but if I copy it, the file is somehow corrupt. I cannot even play it with the normal VideoPlayer in my device.

**It is not a codec error!** If I put the video into my device like on a USB and set the path and it's working with all 3 test videos. The manifest has read and write permission. And the VideoView makes even more problems with the ViewPager and paths.

Hopefully I'm just making some kind of stupid mistake... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Only because you can play the video with the default video player of your device doesn't mean it's not a codec problem or another detail it doesn't like about it.

What I' missing here is a `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener`
If you get something like
`/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)`, which indicates a `MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN` with the extra info `MEDIA_ERROR_SYSTEM (-2147483648) - low-level system error` it's probably a video issue.

You could take a look at the video metadata with ffmpeg:

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4

Check for:

- Codec
- Metadata (e.g. video is rotated)
- Video width/height too big

Didn't get a reasonable error message for any of these.

Here's the official info: [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) which doesn't help much IMHO